# BackgroundWorker for implementing "Search as you type" Combobox

Tags: c#, search, frameworks, combobox, entity

I have created a code for my combobox, that can search addresses in a very large table on Sql Server with the help of stored procedure (i'm working with Entity framework). My stored procedure returns 10 hits and my code fills the combobox with search results. For doing this I'm using BackgroundWorker.

But here I'm now having big problems:
- although the combobox is filled with my search results, it always has the first item selected. Even if I type in only a letter, the whole text gets selected;

- After that searching for the address doesn't work anymore. It searches only among these 10 results and I'm having no idea how to solve this. Here is my whole code, that causes me problems:

  ```
  public String searchedItem = "";    
  public delegate void DelegateUpdateComboboxSelection(ComboBox myCombo,string value,int count);

  BackgroundWorker m_bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();        
  static AutoResetEvent resetWorker = new AutoResetEvent(false);

  m_bgworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
  m_bgworker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(FillComboboxBindingList);
  m_bgworker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted);

  BindingList<spIskalnikNaslovi_Result1> m_addresses = new BindingList<SP_Result1>(); 


  void m_bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
      int count = (int)((object[])e.Result)[0];
      string value = (string)((object[])e.Result)[1];
      ComboBox myCombo = (ComboBox)((object[])e.Result)[2];
      DelegateUpdateComboboxSelection ndelegate = new DelegateUpdateComboboxSelection(UpdateComboSelection);
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
      {
          Invoke(ndelegate, new object[] {myCombo, value, count});
          return; 
      }
      else
      {
          UpdateComboSelection(myCombo, value, count);
          return; 
      }               
  }

  private void UpdateComboSelection(ComboBox myCombo, String value, int count)
  {
      myCombo = comboBox9;
      myCombo.DataSource = m_addresses;
      searchedItem = myCombo.Text;  
      if (count > 0)
      {
          myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
          myCombo.SelectionLength = searchedItem.Length - value.Length;
          myCombo.DroppedDown = true;
      }
      else
      {
          myCombo.DroppedDown = false;
          myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
      }
  } 

  public void FillComboboxBindingList(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
      if (m_bgworker.CancellationPending)
      {
          resetWorker.Set();
          e.Cancel = true;
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          string value = (String)((Object[])e.Argument)[0];
          List<SP_Result1> result;
          result = _vsebina.SP_searcher(value).ToList<SP_Result1>();
          m_addresses = new BindingList<SP_Result1>();

          foreach (SP_Result1 rez in result)
          {
              if (m_addresses.Contains(rez))
              {
                  continue;
              }
              else
              {
                  m_addresses.Add(rez);
              }
          }
          foreach (SP_Result1 r in m_addresses.ToArray())
          {
              if (!result.Contains(r))
              {
                  m_addresses.Remove(r);
              }
          }
          e.Result = new object[] { rezultat.Count, vrednost, null };
          return;
      }
  }

  private void comboBox9_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
      {
          int searchStart = comboBox9.SelectionStart;
          if (searchStart > 0)
          {
              searchStart--;
              if (searchStart == 0)
              {
                  comboBox9.Text = "";
              }
              else
              {
                  comboBox9.Text = comboBox9.Text.Substring(0, searchStart + 1);
              }
          }
          else 
          {
              searchStart = 0;
          }
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }

  private void comboBox9_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      comboBox9.SelectionStart = 0;
      comboBox9.SelectionLength = 0;
  }

  private void comboBox9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      comboBox9.Text = "";
  }

  private void comboBox9_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
      Search();
  }

  public void Search()
  {
      if (comboBox9.Text.Length < 4)
      {
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          if (m_bgworker.IsBusy)
          {
             m_bgworker.CancelAsync();

             m_bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();
             m_bgworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
             m_bgworker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(FillComboboxBindingList);
             m_bgworker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted);
          }
          m_bgworker.RunWorkerAsync(new object[] { comboBox9.Text, comboBox9 });
      }  
  }
  ```

Maybe can someone enlighten me, what I'm doing wrong. This is first time, that I'm using BackgroundWorker. I have no idea, how
to achieve "search as you type" with combobox in any other way, because my datatable with addresses is quite large (million records).

Thanks in advance for any kind of help or code example.

Vladimir

Edit 1:
Ok, here is my code, before I have used BackGroundWorker. It worked, but it searches very very slow (it can take up to 10 seconds):

```
    private void comboBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox9.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            FillCombobox(comboBox9.Text, comboBox9);
        }

    }

    public void FillCombobox(string value, ComboBox myCombo)
    {
        List<spIskalnikNaslovi_Result1> result;
        result = _vsebina.spIskalnikNaslovi1(value).ToList(); 
        if (result.Count() > 0)
        {
            myCombo.DataSource = result;
            myCombo.ValueMember = "HS_MID";
            myCombo.DisplayMember = "NASLOV1";
            var searchedItem = myCombo.Items[0].ToString();
            myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
            myCombo.SelectionLength = searchedItem.Length - value.Length;
            myCombo.DroppedDown = true;
        }
        else
        {
            myCombo.DroppedDown = false;
            myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
        }
        return;
    }
```

Is there a way to speed this up without having backgroundworker?

Comment: Isn't there already a auto-completion mode for your comboBox that you could use, instead of going for a background worker?

Comment: Of course it has a auto-completion mode, but in my case with BackgroundWorker it doesn't work well. I need backgroundWorker, because in normal conditions it would take you too much time (in my case about 10 seconds) for making a search for each typed character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final solution without BackGroundWorker. It works quick with my large table, and is upgraded for using a stored procedure on SQL Server (if you use Entity Framework). I use Timer to make sure the user can find a value, that he is searching.

Here you can see the original solution, that I found on this site (thanks to **Max Lambertini** and **algreat**  for the idea and working concept):

[C# winforms combobox dynamic autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete)

My solution:

```
    private bool _canUpdate = true;
    private bool _needUpdate = false;
    List<spIskalnikNaslovi_Result1> dataFound;

    private void comboBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_needUpdate)
        {
            if (_canUpdate)
            {
                _canUpdate = false;
                refreshData();
            }
            else
            {
                restartTimer();
            }
        }
    }

    private void comboBox12_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            int searchStart = comboBox12.SelectionStart;
            if (searchStart > 0)
            {
                searchStart--;
                if (searchStart == 0)
                {
                    comboBox12.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    comboBox12.Text = comboBox12.Text.Substring(0, searchStart + 1);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                searchStart = 0;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox12_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _needUpdate = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _canUpdate = true;
        timer1.Stop();
        refreshData();
    }

    private void refreshData()
    {
        if (comboBox12.Text.Length > 1)
        {
            FillCombobox(comboBox12.Text, comboBox12);
        }
    }

    private void restartTimer()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        _canUpdate = false;
        timer1.Start();
    }


    private void FillCombobox(string value, ComboBox myCombo)
    {
        dataFound = _vsebina.spIskalnikNaslovi1(value).ToList();
        if (dataFound.Count() > 0)
        {
            myCombo.DataSource = dataFound;
            myCombo.ValueMember = "HS_MID";
            myCombo.DisplayMember = "NASLOV1";
            var searchedItem = myCombo.Items[0].ToString();
            myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
            myCombo.SelectionLength = searchedItem.Length - value.Length;
            myCombo.DroppedDown = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            myCombo.DroppedDown = false;
            myCombo.SelectionStart = value.Length;
            return;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make a button you will call searchbutton
and in click_event of this button call your search() method that run your backgroundworker
that fill the combobox
clear you key_press event of your combobox and it will work
the mistake is you key_press event that call every key stroke happening your search method
so retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

You should get your items in a list, use that list to populate your combobox.

then set `AutoCompleteMode` property value to Suggest or Append or SuggestAppend and set `AutoCompleteSoucre` property value to ListItems.

Comment: My ComboBox has SuggestAppend and as AutoCompleteSource it has ListItems. Autocompletion worked with my previous code. It was just painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

For "Search as you Type", which is actually "Filter as you Type" more than search, you need to implement the OnKeyDown or KeyPressed event.

What you would do is take the search string, which is the current text at the time of the event, then filter the master list using that string.  Normally one would use "Starts With" for the filtering, but you could also simply use "Contains".  Then you live update the contents of the box with the results from the filter.  This is accomplished by changing and refreshing the Datasource.