# Prevent .NET ComboBox from automatically selecting pre-defined values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a ComboBox with some pre-defined values. The user can also type into the ComboBox if the pre-defined values aren't enough. However, if the user types something into the ComboBox and it matches one of the pre-defined values, the ComboBox looks to be automatically selecting that value, which is behavior I do not want. It is weird because the user will be typing and suddenly the typing cursor goes to the start of the ComboBox field.

For example, if one of my pre-defined values was the hex value `0x0D`, and the user wanted to type `0x0D0x0A`, after they typed `0x0D` the cursor would go to the start of the ComboBox, and it might end up looking like this instead `0x0A0x0D`. Can I stop the ComboBox from exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: have u try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Those properties for my control are set to false.

Comment: I got into trouble for suggesting this, but I add an extra "first value" called "<Please Select a value>" with a value of -1.  Not perfect, but in SSRS the users now generally expect that (or Select ALL)

Comment: ok and [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete)

Comment: I don't want it to autocomplete, I want the user to be able to type without having the ComboBox select one of its pre-defined values.