# combobox Autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I want to create a auto complete tools using **combobox**.

So i just add some items to my combobox .And set these items as a source of my combobox.

In `form_load` i do this:

```
private void frmInvoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.Append;
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; 
}
```

But it doesn't work and when i type a letter the whole word doesn't appear in combobox.Why ?

i follow this link :http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx

best regards.

Comment: Since you've declared CustomSource for autocompletion, you should provide that source: `comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;`

Comment: [Visit Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete) for the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've declared ***CustomSource*** for auto completion, you should *provide* that source:

```
private void frmInvoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.Append;
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; 

    AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    // Put here the auto completions' e.g. 
    data.Add("My String 1");
    data.Add("Autocompletion 2");
    data.Add("Some stuff");

    comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;
}
```

Comment: thanks ,but one question ,how can i prevent to add my items one by one to my AutoCompleteStringCollection .i get my data from database as a string  list collection,how can i set my colelction as a datasource for AutoCompleteStringCollection ?

Comment: Suppose my 'var q=myUserRepository.getall().tolist()?

Comment: Look at `AddRange()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx something like data.AddRange(myUserRepository.Select(record => record.SomeStringField()).ToArray())

Answer (score 1):

You didn't upload your CustomSource.

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent(); 
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange
(new string[] {"Raj Beniwal", "Rohit Malhotra", "Ronit Singh", "Ravi Kumar",
"Rohit Behl", "Sanjay Singh", "Shalini Singh", "Seema Malhotra", "Savi Verma",
"Karan Kappor", "Kapil Malhotra", "Vikash Nanda", "Vikram Jain", "Amit Garg",
"Atul Wadhwani", "Ashwani Pandey"
}); 

this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

Refference from : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/2050/autocomplete-combobox-in-visual-C-Sharp-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is use a 3rd party dlls. These are of Telerik. My code is as follows

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible" AllowDrop="True"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AvailList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboboxItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsEditable="True" 
                 telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="DisplayName" Height="17" Margin="10,34,39,0" />
```

This is in xaml. It directly reads from the ItemSource and does the autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this...

```
private void LoadStuffNames()
{

    try
    {
            string Query = "select stuff_name from dbo.stuff";
            string[] names = GetColumnData_FromDB(Query);

            comboName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            comboName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection x = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            if (names != null && names.Length > 0)
                foreach (string s in names)
                    x.Add(s);

            comboName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    }

}
```

Cheers..