# c# Listview Search using Textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, database, listview, search

I Have a c# windows form that can save `ID, Name,`and`Birthday` into my `Employee` Table. I use these codes to save data in my table Using `Save Button`:

```
private void Save_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MainDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter employee = new MainDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter();
            employee.InsertQuery(textBox1.Text.Trim(),
                textBox2.Text.Trim(),
                textBox3.Text.Trim());


            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

with this Query:

> INSERT INTO Employee
>                            (ID, Name, Birthday) VALUES        (@ID,@Name,@Birthday)

I Use `Populate Button` to show my saved data from my Database into `Listview` using this code:

```
private void Populate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        DataTable dtable = mainDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Employee"];

        for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(drow["ID"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(drow["Name"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(drow["Birthday"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

So my Problem now is that I don't have any Idea on how to put a search in my `listview` using a `textbox` and `SearchButton`.

I have a `SearchQuery`:

> SELECT        ID, Name, Birthday FROM            Employee WHERE
>   (Name = @Name)

and I thought I can insert this in my `SearchButton` but I don't know how.

Please somebody Help.

Before I used this code to Populate my listview

```
 DataTable dtable = mainDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Employee"];
```

I used this codes to Search and it worked. I set my DB Connection Using this Code:

```
 public SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = C:\...\...\...");
```

Then I inserted this codes in my `SearchButton`:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlCeCommand search = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee Where Name like '%" + Search.Text + "%'", connection);


        try
        {
            SqlDataReader datareader = search.ExecuteReader();


            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(datareader["ID"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(datareader["Name"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(datareader["Birthday"].ToString());


                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }


        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

but this is not what my teacher wants. He wanted to see how I do the search using this code to populate the Listview

```
DataTable dtable = mainDatabaseDataSet.Tables["Employee"];
```

I know someone here could have an Idea on how to do this. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried combobox ??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete

Comment: what do you mean @kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also filter datarow. Refer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx

like dtable.Select(Name=textbox1.text);

Comment: I used these code but I don't have any Idea where and how I will put this in my Search Button dtable.Select("Name like '%" + textBox4.Text + "%'");

Comment: When you click search button to write textbox some text. It should be   create event of this button and write code in this event.

Comment: You can already filter data in query. SqlCeCommand search = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee Where Name like '%" + Search.Text + "%'", connection);
Do not need this code  dtable.Select("Name like '%" + Search.Text + "%'");

Answer (score 0):

You can set [dtable.DefaultView.RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property in `SearchButton` click handler and iterate `DataTable.DefaultView` instead of table rows in `Populate_Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it on my own.
Thanks for glancing in my question. Here's the Code that I used

```
 public MainDatabaseDataSet.EmployeeDataTable getData(string data)
    {
        MainDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter returnEmployee = new MainDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter();
        return returnEmployee.GetDataByName(this.textBox4.Text.Trim());
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        try
        {

            MainDatabaseDataSet.EmployeeDataTable GetName = getData(this.Search.Text);
            MainDatabaseDataSet.EmployeeRow GetName2 = (MainDatabaseDataSet.EmployeeRow)GetName.Rows[0];


            for (int i = 0; i < GetName.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow drow = GetName.Rows[i];

                if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(drow["ID"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(drow["Name"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(drow["Birthday"].ToString());

                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }


            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You should accept an answer, even if it's this one, as then the problem is recorded as solved in Stack Overflow. Click on the green tick.