# WinForms: providing text editor with dynamic suggestions popup

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to implement something like **Google's search bar** behavior for our application: user must be able to enter user name as free text and based on entered data system must provide a couple of suggestions on a popup bar based on already existent user names.

---

Here's the brief algorithm:

- user enters some character to text edit box
- system fires some changing event with web service call inside it that updates suggestions list data
- Text edit must also provide an ability to enter and keep a free text to create new user, not just looking up for existent

I can't use `devexpress`'s lookupeditds - they allow to keep only values, presented in datasource - even if new value has being processed inside `ProcessNewValue` by adding to datasource,

Changing event fires one more time with refreshing my datasource overwriting new unique value.
Now I am looking forward Combobox control. But looks like there is no ability to enter free text alongside with displaying suggestions popup.

Comment: If you're open to third party libraries, the Infragistics NetAdvantage for Windows Forms has a great auto-suggest combo box that we use extensively. It does exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mangist thanks for your suggestion. Not sure it's possible in my project :-(

Comment: you can use a regular Windows Forms combo then, and use the AutoCompleteMode property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx  as the user types, you will have to hit the database and then reload the list of Items in the ComboBox. I would use DataSource, DisplayMember, ValueMember. You can make it work, I think.

Comment: Check this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete), it could be useful to do what you need.

Comment: I have a code that works something like you suggest. The problem is that after calling for new suggests combobox automatically selects one of the values without a chance to continue editing a free text.

Comment: I don't know about the ASP side, but the Dx Winforms has a MRU edit that, I believe does this.  Maybe check the controls for an MRU edit on the web side and see if it has this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use devexpress's lookup edits - they allow to keep only values, presented in datasource - even if new value has being processed inside ProcessNewValue by adding to datasource,

I believe you're wrong here because you can use the DevExpress LookUpEdit with easy:

```
class AutoCompleteLookUpEdit : LookUpEdit {
    List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    public AutoCompleteLookUpEdit() {
        Properties.DataSource = suggestions;
        Properties.ImmediatePopup = true;
    }
    protected override void ProcessFindItem(KeyPressHelper helper, char pressedKey) {
        suggestions.Clear();
        // add search suggestions here depending on helper.Text value
        suggestions.Add("google");
        suggestions.Add("devexpress");
        // ...
        base.ProcessFindItem(helper, pressedKey);
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [How to create an editor with a dynamic autocomplete list](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3132) for the detailed example.

P.S. You can use the [AcceptEditorTextAsNewValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument116019) property to control whether or not lookup accepts entered text as valid value even it does not belong the underlying data source.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same result - after leaving editor it contains [Edit Value is null] instead of new value...

Comment: The only way to keep entered value is to add them to datasource, but i dont want it to be visible alongside with actual suggestions.

Comment: Finally got it - new values must be processed inside ProcessNewValue event. Now it works seamless and as expected! Thank you so much Dmitry!