# Autosuggestion datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a c# windows forms  project where my requirement is to create a autosuggestion datagridview much like similar to autocomplete text box . I have managed to link  the datagridview with  a text box in  which as soon as I type in the text box , the datagridview pop-ups and give me suggestions but the problem is I want that when I press up and down arrow keys while focusing in the text box , the selected row of the datagridview should also change .

Comment: Are you sure you're an Editable Combobox would not be a better solution for your problem? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete

Comment: No sir , I have to show multiple columns .That's why I think datagridview is more suitable in my need .

Comment: What do you mean by… _”I want that when I press up and down arrow keys while focusing in the text box , the selected row of the datagridview should also change._” … ? … If the auto complete text box is the active cell and the user is editing the cell using the arrow keys to scroll up or down in the list of suggested items… then … “when” should the selected grid row change?